# CMake for Proto libraires

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, proto

I have two Proto files across two different folders and am trying to use CMake for building the overall project.

- protofile1 has protofile2 as it's dependency.
- Library1 has protofile1 as it's dependency which I can generate using `protobuf_generate_cpp`.

But for generating protofile1, I have protofile2 as it's dependency. How do I do this using CMake?

How do I compile proto file and make it available as a library using CMake (in folder2)?

Folder Structure:

```
|
|-folder1
---|-protofile1.proto
---|-library1.cc
|-folder2
---|-protofile2.proto
---|-library2.cc
```

CMakeLists.txt for folder1

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
protobuf_generate_cpp(protofile1_cc protofile1_header protofile1.proto)
target_link_libraries(protofile1_cc INTERFACE protofile2_lib) # is this correct?

add_library(library1 INTERFACE)
target_sources(library1 INTERFACE library1.cc)
target_link_libraries(library1 INTERFACE protofile1_cc)
```

CMakeLists.txt for folder2

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
# don't know how to do this
add_library(protofile2_lib INTERFACE) # is this correct?
target_sources(protofile2_lib INTERFACE protofile2.proto) # is this correct?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`protobuf_generate_cpp`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindProtobuf.html#command:protobuf_generate_cpp) command does not define *targets*, but it defines CMake *variables* referring to the auto-generated source files (`.cc`, `.h`). These variables should be used to define your targets via `add_library()`. You are on the right track, but your CMakeLists.txt file in `folder2` should also call `protobuf_generate_cpp` to process `protofile2.proto` as well.

Also, if you're using CMake to build both, the top-level CMake (in the parent folder to `folder1` and `folder2`) can find Protobuf so you don't have to find it twice. Something like this should get you closer to the desired solution:

CMakeLists.txt (top-level):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
add_subdirectory(folder2)
add_subdirectory(folder1)
```

folder2/CMakeLists.txt

```
# Auto-generate the source files for protofile2.
protobuf_generate_cpp(protofile2_cc protofile2_header protofile2.proto)
# Use the CMake variables to add the generated source to the new library.
add_library(protofile2_lib SHARED ${protofile2_cc} ${protofile2_header})
# Link the protobuf libraries to this new library.
target_link_libraries(protofile2_lib PUBLIC ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES})
```

folder1/CMakeLists.txt

```
# Auto-generate the source files for protofile1.
protobuf_generate_cpp(protofile1_cc protofile1_header protofile1.proto)
# Use the CMake variables to add the generated source to the new library.
add_library(library1 SHARED ${protofile1_cc} ${protofile1_header})
# Link proto2 library to library1.
target_link_libraries(library1 INTERFACE protofile2_lib)
```

Comment: But the thing is protofile1 has protofile2 as it's dependency and thus needs it during the build. How to go about that?
What you suggested was linking proto2 lib with library1. Rather, proto1 needs proto2. And library1 needs proto1.

Comment: @ChinmayShah That is how I set up the dependencies. If there are other sources to add to `library1`, then those can simply be appended to the `add_library()` command. The protofile1 has access to the protofile2 implementation "during the build", specifically during the link stage. Do you need the protofile2 headers as well? I'm not sure what you mean by "during the build" as this is a vague term. Do you mean auto-generate step, compile step, link step, etc...

Comment: For some reason, it says protofile1.pb.h not found as protofile2 has protofile1 as it's dependency.